# Qual a diferença entre os comentários "/*" e "/**" em PHP?

Tags: php

Sempre tive curiosidade sobre isto, mas como nunca mudou a minha vida em nada, nunca procurei saber.

Se existe diferença, qual seria entre estes tipos de comentários em PHP?

```
/* Comentário 1 */

/** Comentário 2 */
```

Comment: Correta a resposta do @rray. Inclusive, tente utilizar dois astericos no início no sublime text e na linha abaixo não incie com outro asterisco. Ele vai marcar como erro. Se você deixar apenas um asterisco, vai reconhecer como comentário de multiplas linhas, comum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/* Comentário 1 */`, é um comentário mesmo assim com `//` ou `#`. É curioso comentar que nenhum tipo de comentário anula a taga de fechamento `?>`

`/** Comentário 2 */`, é chamado de doclet o que estiver dentro dele, geralmente anotado com arroba `@` é uma ou mais informações que alguns frameworks leem para tornar a configuração de certos recursos mais fáceis, dessa forma não é preciso configurar algum xml ou arquivo externo.

Caso algum configuração seja obrigatória e você esqueça o segundo asterisco, vai ter um pouco de dor de cabeça caso não saiba essa sutil diferença.

Veja um exemplo retirado do [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#mapping-a-url-to-a-controller) de como configurar uma rota, pode ser feito através de um xml, yaml ou arquivo php.

```
class HelloController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

Essa informação ainda pode ser utilizada por IDEs para oferecer um autocomplete melhor por exemplo com definir o tipo do parâmetro de entrada ou saída além disso pode ser utilizado para gerar documentação.

Comment: rray, era +/- isso que imaginava, pois sempre via *doclets* destes bem extensos com possíveis funções, imaginei que poderia ter algum funcionalidade e de fato tem. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 5):

Os comentários com o segundo * podem ser usados, por exemplo, para gerar documentação.

Todas as frameworks que conheço em PHP utilizam o segundo * para posteriormente gerar documentação do código.

Uma ferramente para gerar documentação de códigos PHP é o [PHPDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/).

Isso poupa bastante tempo na hora de escrever a documentação.