# Existem diferenças entre //, /* */ e #?

Tags: php

Considerando **o quanto que é importante comentar um código**, me surgiu essa questão.

---

Percebi que existem várias **formas de comentar linhas/partes do código**:

- `//`
- `/* */`
- `#`

---

#### Exemplo:

```
// comentando uma linha

/* comentando
   um intervalo
   do código */

# comentando uma linha
```

---

#### Dúvidas:

- Existem outras formas de comentar?
- Tirando essas definições do exemplo, **existem mais diferenças entre elas**?

Comment: Downvoter, como posso melhorar a pergunta para você? 

Comment: Varia de linguagem, no `Delphi` por exemplo cometário em bloco usamos `{}`.
As diferenças você mesmo já pontuou na sua pergunta.

Comment: Boa @rbz, não tinha parado para pensar se há diferenças entre os tipo comentários

Comment: @RobertodeCampos A minha dúvida principal mesmo é entre `//` e `#`... Será que é para não "atrapalhar" um caso de quebra? Exemplo: `\/n`... Valeu Wees! ✌️

Comment: OBS: Não fui em quem negativou.
Tudo o que estiver após `\\`, `#` ou entre `/**/` será interpretado pelo compilador, a não ser, que esteja dentro de uma `string`. Então `\\/n` não mudará em nada no seu código, `#/n` também não.

Comment: Acho q a "diferença" é a origem, // é estilo c++ ; # é estilo shell, mas só isso mesmo.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta é só somente sobre PHP, não temos nem porque falar de C ou Delphi, também não entendo porque downvotes, eu vejo essa pergunta como uma excelente maneira de ajudar programadores iniciantes e tornar isto tudo em uma ótima fonte de pesquisa.

Comment: Para sql usa-se `--`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O essencial é isso:

- O `//` e o `#` são idênticos em termos de funcionamento;
- O `//` e o `/*` são completamente diferentes em termos de funcionamento, e cada um tem um cenário específico de uso:

  O `//` ou `#` são para **comentários de linha**. Tudo que vem depois deles é ignorado, até que se encontre uma quebra de linha.

  Já, o `/*` é um **comentário de bloco** que pode terminar: 1) antes do fim da linha; ou 2) em linha diferente de onde começou. Em ambos os casos o que determina o fim do comentário é a sequência `*/`;
- Tem uma terceira situação, o **[`__halt_compiler`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72473/70)**, que não é *comment*, mas também faz com que o código seja ignorado daquele ponto em diante (pode ser usado para "ignorar" um comentário mais extenso, ou até ter uma função especial para reuso do arquivo fonte).

No mais, nada de diferenças.

**Notas:**

- Você não pode aninhar comentários de bloco.

  ```
  /* abc /* 123 */ def */
  ```

  no caso acima, o def não está mais comentado, vai dar erro. O primeiro `*/` é que vale. (O fato é que o segundo `/*` é ignorado).
- Tem uma técnica para "chavear" comentários de bloco bem curiosa, que é essa (créditos à seção de comentários do PHP):

  Quando você define um bloco assim, basta modificar uma barra para ele "valer" ou não:

  ```
  //*
      Bloco "chaveável" com várias linhas.
      Em princípio, são duas linhas com "comment de linha"
      Basta modificar UMA barra, que vira um "comment de bloco"
  // */
  ```

  Tirando apenas a primeira barra:

  ```
  /*
      Bloco "chaveável" com várias linhas.
      Em princípio, são duas linhas com "comment de linha"
      Basta modificar UMA barra, que vira um "comment de bloco"
  // */
  ```
- Tem um tipo de comentário que é usado em ferramentas de documentação (não faz parte da linguagem em si) que é o `/**`. Na prática é um comentário de bloco normal `/*` seguido de um asterisco (apesar de que, [foi adotado um token especial para esse caso no parser](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=T_DOC_COMMENT&unscoped_q=T_DOC_COMMENT), o `T_DOC_COMMENT`).

  Para saber mais detalhes, veja este post:

  [Qual a diferença entre os comentários "/*" e "/**" em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94374/70)

Comment: Há alguma diferença na performance do tipo de comentário por parte do compilador? Tipo a diferença entre `'nome: ' . $nome` e `"nome: {$nome}"`... Pensando na parte do bloco de comentário o compilador teria que achar o inicio e o fim, custando um pouco mais - certo, ou é irrelevante?

Comment: @PapaCharlie em qualquer caso o trabalho é o mesmo, só muda o marcador de fim, que em um caso é  `\n` e no outro é `*/` - O que influi mesmo é a quantidade de caracteres no comment, mas mesmo assim é desprezivel (se a pessoa está usando PHP e não uma linguagem compilada, provavelmente esses detalhes são irrelevantes - a diferença de tempo é irrisória e a aplicação não é crítica)

Comment: Não seria interessante frisar que nenhum tipo de comentário anula a tag de fechamento ?>

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo vou dar uma confirmada se é válido para todas as versões, e atualizo depois (com o devido crédito)

Comment: Dai a Cesar o que é de Cesar e a Deus o que é de Deus!! O credito é de @rray veja nessa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94374/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-tipos-de-coment%C3%A1rios-em-php/94383#94383

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Muito interessante e válido sobre o `/**` ! 

Comment: Muito bom esse negócio de bloco chaveável de varias linhas. Vou usar muito a partir de agora!